# Is it possible to append code into JavaScript files using File System in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, code-generation, fs

I am creating a generator that should insert certain lines of code into a .JS file based on the users choices. In my experience with File System for Node.JS I have only ever written to .txt or .json files.

How would I go about appending this code into the file? Is this possible? Should I use specific encoding?

**UPDATE** 
I did some lightweight experimentation by setting up an application like so:

```
-app.js 
-index.js
-snippet.js
-index.html
```

Inside `app.js` I have the following code.

```
const fs = require("fs");


fs.readFile("snippet.js", function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    var file_content = data.toString();
    fs.writeFile("index.js", file_content, (err)=>{
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("File Written");
    });
});
```

Then I am taking a simple `alert("File System Insert")` from `snippet.js` and writing it to `index.js` and once `index.html` is loaded the alert functions as expected. So yes, it is possible to pass javascript code using File System.

I guess my next step would be to figure out how to template it without the use of template engine file extensions.

Comment: A text file is a text file. Just go for it.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @doublesharp Thanks for the feedback. Code posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a templating engine for this purpose.

For example, take a look at [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

You can have a template like this (`file.template`):

```
let greetings = 'hello world!'
{{ optionalCode }}
console.log(greetings)
```

Then use Mustache and compile the template, populate the `{{ optionalCode }}` with your desired JS code and get the final JS file.

Read the Mustache's documentations for [Node.js](https://github.com/raycmorgan/Mu) and [JavaScript](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

---

There are other templating libraries as well. Check the following link for more:
https://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-templating-engines/

Comment: This is pretty cool, and I kind of wanted to use a solution like this except without forcing the end user into having to use template engine file extensions like to `.template`. I'd like to keep the extensions as `.js`. 
But in essence what I would like to create using File System would work a lot like what you described.

Comment: @SavSamoylov using `.template` was just for showing that it is not a regular JavaScript file.  
 You are free to use any extension (including `.js`) for your template files.

Comment: Oh, in that case I'll take a deeper dive into Mustache. Thanks @KayvanMazaheri.